# Get a dropdown of states in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I made some basic models for a listing of a business, like so:

```
class Business(models.Models):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=225, blank=True)  
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)  
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)   
    state_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=33, blank=True)  
    country = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)  
    url = models.CharField(max_length=765, blank=True)  

class States(models.Model):  
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=96)  
    state_abbr = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=True)
```

In the admin when I edit each business it shows the state_id field. But how do I connect it with the state model to show a select dropdown listing of the states?

Also, how do I show the state abbreviation in the view of a business?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a ForeignKey field.
Make the following changes.

```
class Business(models.Models):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=225, blank=True)  
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)  
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)   
    #state_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    # Define a new state field that creates a ForeignKey relationship with States
    state = models.ForeignKey('States', null=True, blank=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=33, blank=True)  
    country = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)  
    url = models.CharField(max_length=765, blank=True)  

class States(models.Model):  
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=96)  
    state_abbr = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=True)

    #Define the __unicode__ method, which is used by related models by default.
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.state_abbr
```

By default ForeignKey fields append '_id' to the field name when creating the column name in the database. So, the new "state" field in the Business class will automatically use the column "state_id" that you've previously defined, unless you've changed some of the default behavior of Django.

For more on this:

1. Check out [Django's documentation of
   the ForeignKey field](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)
2. [Search "ForeignKey"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=foreignkey) on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Comments below about using the provided localflavor abstraction are well-made. This is especially desirable when a simple list of US states is all that is needed. However, in one of our applications, some states also have other required metadata, and some are completely omitted from the app (unavailable in those states). Maintaining our own table of state data makes the most sense in this case.

Answer (score 11):

An alternative that doesn't require a separate state table:

```
from django.contrib.localflavor.us.us_states import STATE_CHOICES

class Business(models.Models):
    ...
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)  
    ...
```

Comment: Note: localflavor is no longer part of django.contrib as of version 1.6. It's managed separately in an app (available via pip) called django-localflavor.

Answer (score 7):

#### Edit in 2015 (django 1.8)

you should check the django official localflavor repo: https://github.com/django/django-localflavor.

```
from localflavor.us.models import USStateField

class Business(models.Models):
    …
    state = USStateField(null=True, blank=True)
    …
```

Some [tests are available on the repo](https://github.com/django/django-localflavor/blob/master/tests/test_us/models.py) for this specific usage.

Docs available [here](https://django-localflavor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).